# How to add another button beside Delete button, when TableViewCell is swiped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is the code that adds a delete button:

```
 (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return YES;
}


(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSLog(@"delete pressed");

    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please visit this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using UITableViewCell, you need to create your own custom UITableViewCells and lay out those views yourself when the cell enters in edit mode.

Comment: do you know any library that can help me to do that?

Comment: The Apple Docs are pretty good https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1