# Is it possible to remove the delete button in UITableViewCell but keep the VoiceOver Rotor "Action" element?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, voiceover

I am developing a custom UITableViewCell which features extra buttons when sliding on the cell like Apple does in the iOS 7 Mail App. See here: 
[Swipe to Delete and the "More" button (like in Mail app on iOS 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7)

To make a custom UITableViewCell, I need to remove the default delete button by doing something like this:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

However by doing this the VoiceOver Rotor no longer displays the "Actions" element. And I can't add custom elements to the VoiceOver rotor (I can only use Apple's).

So is there any way to hide the default swipe to delete button but still display the "Actions" element in the VoiceOver rotor interface.