# Make row actions appear from the left when table enters edit mode without swipe in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, edit, uitableviewrowaction

I would like to be able to present actions on the row of a `TableView` (as described in the topic "[Swipe to Delete and the More button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7)") from its *left* and *when the table enters edit mode*, and not based on a swipe gesture.

The question "[In iOS 8, how to add Row Action Buttons to the left side of a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939964/in-ios-8-how-to-add-row-action-buttons-to-the-left-side-of-a-uitableviewcell)" discusses this topic and presents a [relevant picture](http://images.apple.com/v/ios/h/images/whats-new/design/read_large.jpg), however this action is initiated by a swipe, where I would like it to be initiated when entering edit mode by tapping an `Edit` button.

When binding the edit mode to an `Edit` button in the navigation bar (on the left) with

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

then tapping the `Edit` button will by default shift the row and present a rounded `delete` button on the left:

[image: table row in edition mode with rounded red delete button on its left]

Is there a simple way to replace this rounded button with square buttons such as `Delete` and `More` (swiping the row should not trigger anyting) ?

Thank your very much.