# Modify or delete table view cell in master-detail ipad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am developing a simple master-detail ipad app. Using xcode template for master-detail app when "Edit" navigation item is pressed in table view cell red circle appears which allows to delete selected cell.
In my app I would like to have the following: when edit button is pressed each cell can be deleted or modified (by performing segue to detail view). In other words with the red circle I would like to have another "icon" to modify the contents of that cell. Is it possible to perform this and how can be it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of stuff in multiple ways.

First is that you assign a custom gesture like swipe on the cell using the UIGestureRecognizer with custom selector that will called each time when the cell is swiped.
You can then display the buttons that are initially hidden from User.

Look into the following post to understand it better - [How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions – Without Going Nuts With Scroll Views](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

Answer (score 0):

You could always instead of using the default Edit button, implement a swipe feature that allows the user to swipe the cell to view more options. [This link](http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/) provides a tutorial walkthrough on how to implement this functionality.

Also, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7) might help as well if this is the direction you choose to take.