# UITableViewCell: Trash Image is shown on cell selection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with the following hierarchy:

[image]

I use `swipe` and `pan` gestures to move the `Container View` to left, so that the trash button is visible, Similar to Instagram:

[image]

But, on cell selection The thrash button is visible:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Please Note:

The `trash button` is actually a custom button with a transparent `png image`. The background colour of the button is then set as `red`.

Please provide your valuable suggestions or a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Change the color which should not be similar to white and check

Comment: write custom UITableViewCell, override - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
animated:(BOOL)animated and - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated ==> set Trash buttom hidden = YES when highlighted or selected; OR maybe you should read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7

Comment: @HussainShabbir change the color of what? I didnt get you.

Comment: What's the question? How to hide the button when selected? How to make the button red when selected?

Comment: The question isn't about hiding anything. From the view hierarchy, you may notice that the trash button lies beneath the container view. Then why does it show on cell selection? My expectation is that it should not show.

Comment: Please see the edit above.

Comment: @HoangVanHa that seems to be an ugly work around. But I will try that if no better solution comes up. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: downVoter: Please provide a valuable suggestion or a solution to the problem. If you don't understand the question, please ask. Downvoting a question blankly doesn't help anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't get a proper answer, I was forced to fix this issue as pointed out by @hoang Van Ha.

In the custom cell class:

I hid the button by overriding setSelected method as follows:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (self.cellContainerView.frame.origin.x == 0) {
        self.trashButton.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

at the beginning of the gesture methods, i.e. `pan` and `swipe` I show the button again and on completing the gesture, I check if the frame of the container view has origin zero. If so, the button should be hidden.

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    self.trashButton.hidden = NO;
    if ( recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         self.cellContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.cellContainerView.frame.origin.y, 320, self.cellContainerView.bounds.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.trashButton.hidden = YES;
                     }
         ];
    }
}
```

In the controller class, in cell for row method, do the same process.

```
 if (cell.cellContainerView.frame.origin.x == 0) {
         cell.trashButton.hidden = YES;
 }
```

Please feel free to comment, or even post a better answer!

Comment: Here is why the image gets visible: When a cell gets highlighted the UITableView goes over all the subViews of the cell and sets their backgroundColor to clear.

Comment: I thought so too. Can you please point me to a blog or a documentation of the same?

Comment: I think this is not documented. I found that a while ago when I tried to prevent this (quite annoying) behavior. If you need to see it yourself you can subclass any UIView and put it in a cell. If you overwrite `setBackgroundColor:` and put a NSLog (or a breakpoint) in you can see how highlight changes the backgroundColor to clear and unhighlight changes it back.

Comment: Yep I tried that out. That is exactly whats happening. Thanks @MatthiasBauch :)! If you post that as an answer, I will surely accept it.