# How to make UITableViewcell editable for using swipe and delete feature in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios8

I am trying to implement delete button in UITableView on `iOS8` in `objective-c`, but in `iOS8` swipe and delete feature is not work as work in `iOS7`. can any one please help me how to implement this feature in `iOS8` table view.

I want to do this in objective-c not in Swift.

I am using this code,

```
  - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([myDataArray count]>0)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
    }


    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Called when "DELETE" button is pushed.


      cellIndex=indexPath.row;
      }
```

If any one know about this how can i do this, then please help me, in detail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Go through the link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7

It might help you.

Comment: This will help you to implement swipe table view in iOS 8, follow the tutorial and download the custom class provided in Github http://www.appcoda.com/?s=swipe+tableview