# How to achieve swipe right to complete (Todo List)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe, swift2

I'm working on a todo list app, and now I can use these code to achieve swipe left to delete

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Delete button tapped")
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return [delete]
}
```

And I think I searched the WHOLE internet but none of those solutions can do the swipe right job and work fine on me at the same time. I'm using swift 2.0, Xcode 7 beta 5.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to swipe right to show other action(s) in the cell's left?

Comment: Yes, like mark as unread, etc. @Siam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swipe to Delete and the "More" button (like in Mail app on iOS 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think this project can help you further...

[SBGestureTableView](https://github.com/Stickbuilt/SBGestureTableView): Swift UITableView subclass that supports swiping rows ala Mailbox and long press to move rows.

If you don't want to use this class. You can see in there source code, you first need to figure out if the user is swiping from left-to-right or right-to-left. And go from there.

Comment: I tried this one. Lots of syntax error and unknown error that I can't even run it.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version also running xcode 7 and swift 2 and it is just working :-)

Comment: which beta do you use? @Peter

Comment: Which branch (SBGestureTableView) are you running? Did you clicked that `update to latest Swift syntax button`?

Comment: Yes. The main branch. No I didnt convert anything. Xcode also did not ask.

Comment: but my Xcode asked me to convert, are you sure you're using Xcode 7 beta?

Comment: I cant seem to run only one action?

Answer (score 2):

Use commit editing style

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TaskModel

    if thisTask.completed ==  true {thisTask.completed = false}
    else {thisTask.completed = true}
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

I'm using CoreData to store my information, and one of the things I'm storing is wether it's completed or not, when a use swipes right on a tableview it changes the completed to true, and I have two sections, one for uncompleted tasks and one for completed

Comment: I removed `let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TaskModel

    if thisTask.completed ==  true {thisTask.completed = false}
    else {thisTask.completed = true}
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()` and it's not working

Comment: You need the objectAtIndexPath since that tells the program which one to delete

Answer (score 0):

I've finally done this by successfully converted `SBGestureTableView` to swift 2.0 syntax and I published that on [github.com/theniceboy/SBGestureTableView/tree/swift-2.0](https://github.com/theniceboy/SBGestureTableView/tree/swift-2.0). But I still have to thank you guys!